# FBRequestConnection method in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, string, facebook, swift, nsstring

[ORIGINAL QUESTION] *How to pass a string to a method with NSString in Swift 1.2*

I'm stucked with a problem with String and NSString. With Facebook SDK I'm using:

```
FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/me/feed", parameters: params, HTTPMethod: NSString(string:"POST"), completionHandler:{(connection:FBRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError?) -> Void in .... my code here ...})
```

Before 1.2 was working just fine, but now I don't know what to do, I've tried with HTTPMethod:

```
HTTPMethod: NSString(string:"POST") as! /*(and also as? and as)*/ String
```

But nothing seems to work. I also used **HTTPMethod: "POST"**, but also is an issue (Because NSString is required by the function)

**"'NSString' is not implicitly convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?"** is the error.

And also:
**Cannot invoke 'startWithGraphPath' with an argument list of type '(String, parameters: NSDictionary!, HTTPMethod: String, completionHandler: FBRequestHandler)'** *(If I use just the string)*

How can avoid this problem?

[UPDATE]
It seems the problem is with the parameters:

I have:

```
params = NSDictionary(dictionary: [
            "contentTitle" : _nameTxt.string,
            "caption" : _captionTxt.string,
            "contentDescription" : _descriptionTxt.string,
            "contentURL" : "http://somelink.com/index.php",
            "imageURL" : "http://somelink.com/media/image.png"
            ])
```

When I try:
parameters: nil, the app compiles
but with parameters: params, I get an error

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just do HTTPMethod = "POST"

Comment: Nope. "Cannot invoke 'startWithGraphPath' with an argument list of type '(String, parameters: NSDictionary!, HTTPMethod: String, completionHandler: FBRequestHandler)'" is the problem in that case

Comment: Ok, the problem are not the strings but the parameters. I've edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after trying with "parameters: nil" and compiling the app, I figured that the problem wasn't only with NSString but also with NSDictionary. Now (and better I think) I should use all Swift natives.

So:
*"me/feed" and "POST"* must be **String**.
*parameters: params* must be **Dictionary**